# How to use Selenium's ExpectedCondition with Function.andThen?

Tags: java, selenium

I don't seem to figure out how to use Selenium 3.7.1's `ExpectedCondition`s in a chain with `Function.andThen`. The minimal reduction of the issue the following compilation failure which I hope you don't consider off-topic because it's really tricky and there're no examples or docs giving me any clue:

```
WebElement webElement0 = null;
Function<WebDriver, WebElement> function0 = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement0);
Function<WebDriver, WebElement> function1 = ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement0).andThen(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement0));
```

fails due to

```
richtercloud/selenium/and/then/NewMain.java:[25,97] method andThen in interface java.util.function.Function<T,R> cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,? extends V>
  found: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) V
    (argument mismatch; org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,? extends V>)
```

Since `andThen` has the signature `public <V> Function<T,V> andThen(Function<? super R,? extends V> after)` adding `ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(webElement0).<WebElement>andThen(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(webElement0));` should help, but fails due to

```
richtercloud/selenium/and/then/NewMain.java:[20,157] incompatible types: org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement> cannot be converted to java.util.function.Function<? super org.openqa.selenium.WebElement,? extends org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>
```

Why does the `Function` passed to `andThen` want to have `<? super WebElement, ? extends V>` when all other `Function`s returned from `ExpectedConditions` use something derived from `WebDriver` as first and the outcome as seconds argument.

I'm aware that it's easy to work around this issue. I'd like to broaden my skills to write shorter code which is imo easier to understand.